# what arguments need with open: integer is required error

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm facing an issue with the open statement. I do not know why is expecting a integer

```
import urllib

site_url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boroughs_of_New_York_City'
r = urllib.request.urlopen(site_url)
site_content = r.read().decode('utf-8')

with open('saved_page.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(site_content)
```

This is the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-993aea7cff16> in <module>
     12 site_content = r.read().decode('utf-8')
     13 
---> 14 with open('saved_page.html', 'w','utf-8') as f:
     15     f.write(site_content)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match the traceback. And why did you include half a dozen unused imports?

Comment: Is so strange , I tested with python3 and was OK....( I commented import seaborn as sns)

Comment: Please format and indent properly.

Comment: Strangely, I get another error altogether: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2010' in position 128753: character maps to <undefined>`

Answer (score 2):

You passed 'utf-8' as the third positional argument. However, when you look up the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) you'll see that that's actually for `buffering`. The encoding comes after that. So you should pass it as a keyword argument:

```py
with open('saved_page.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(site_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works under python 3.6.3

```
import urllib.request as request

site_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boroughs_of_New_York_City'
r = request.urlopen(site_url)
site_content = r.read().decode('utf-8')

with open('saved_page.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(site_content)
```